# what is "oh" method in rails 2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The code below is from comments controller. What is "oh" doing in line 3?

```
@offer = Offer.find(params[:offer_id])
@offer_comment = @offer.offer_comments.build(params[:offer_comment])
@offer_comment.commenter oh = current_user
@offer_comment.save!
Notify::offer_comment_create(@offer_comment)
@offer.update_attribute(:read, false) if @offer.read? and current_user == @offer.offerer
```

Comment: Why it is voted down? Who are the haters :(.

Comment: My guess is they think you could have figured the question out. Probably the same is true for the close votes. I disagree, because if you're not an experienced Ruby developer you probably wouldn't understand that `oh = current_user`. I think that the code was written very poorly, and your reaction to it only proves that they've created a maintenance problem by not using parenthesis, especially so because they didn't use them consistently, which fools the eyes and brain. So don't feel bad, it's a poor example of how to write Ruby code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ruby will see that line as:

```
@offer_comment.commenter(oh = current_user)
```

So it'll assign `current_user` to `oh` and `commenter` will receive `current_user` as it's argument.

Answer (score 2):

It is creating a new local variable named `oh` and assigning the result of `current_user` to it. However, the variable is never used anywhere else, so it's basically a no-op.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby allows methods without surrounding parenthesis, but I personally use them because of just this type of situation. While Ruby can usually sort it out and understand based on its order of precedence rules, it can still be a maintenance and support problem.

It is harder for us humans to read, especially if we jump in and out of different languages all the time, and those languages use different rules for method parameters. This is evidenced by the different answers to this question, because the meaning of the statement was difficult to discern. (One of the answers has been deleted, but it's still visible to those of us with high-enough rankings.)

I've programmed a long time, and, though the Ruby style guides say differently, I use parenthesis almost all the time, and insist on it in our team at work. When debugging, those parenthesis can be the difference between finding a bug quickly or spending hours to find it.

Comment: I differ in that when it's something DSLish I won't use them, though most DSLish-things are specifically built to tolerate this. In this case I think not using them is Really Bad. The answer would be better if it was an answer too, though ;)

Comment: I agree about DSLs, they tend to be much more readable. Eh, my answer was more a rant that didn't end with "...and get off my lawn!" :-) If I saw `@offer_comment.commenter oh = current_user` in code, my first thought would be "Oh, they forgot the carriage-return and didn't put that on the next line", causing an additional error.

Comment: Yeah, it combines two smells into one (no parens, embedded assignment), making intent difficult to determine.